# Bot staying offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

I've tried to create a bot on discord, and with multiple tutorials, I've followed all of the instructions, and it seems to work fine in the beginning. However, with all of the tutorials, I'm met with one problem. In my index.js file for my bot, when I open the VSCode terminal and type in the command `node index.js` (which is supposed to make my bot go online, I get the following error messages:

```
/Users/myname/Desktop/testbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:544
    throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
    ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (/Users/myname/Desktop/testbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (/Users/myname/Desktop/testbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myname/Desktop/testbot/index.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}
```

I have node.js 16.13.0, and discord.js installed. My bot is a member of my server, but it's always offline. What can I do to fix it?

Here's the code for index.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = '[not putting my token online]';
const PREFIX = '';

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Online!');


});
bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you don't have intents added with your bot which is needed to get it running according to the [discord.js starter guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-main-file)

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const token = 'your token here';

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

Comment: Ok, that fixed the problem. However, once I quit VSCode, the bot goes offline. How can I keep it online permanently?

Comment: Look into getting a dedicated hosting server for your bot, for example Google Cloud or AWS. Services such as those allow you to run code on a virtual machine and keep it running 24/7.

Comment: @AngelR. This is a different problem unrelated to the question. If this solved your issue give it a check mark to mark it as THE answer